# Term for nouns strung together by conjunctions

Tags: nouns, compounds

In the sentence:

> Men, women and children are people.

What is the term for the combination of nouns and conjunctions found in the subject position?

"Compound noun" doesn't quite seem to fit the bill here.

Comment: It is just a subject with three NPs in distributive coordination. Distributive here means that the property of being people applies to 'men', 'woman' and 'children' separately - it's distributed between them. (cf. 'Lee, Robin and Sam like each other', which is an example of "joint coordination" in which the property of liking each other can only apply to them jointly. as a group)

Comment: The general term is a _coordinate structure_. This is the term made famous in the [Coordinate Structure Constraint](http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~kehler/Papers/Kehler-BLS-1996.pdf), which forbids extraction from one conjunct in a coordinate structure: _the dishes that he washed_, but not *_the dishes that he washed and swept the floor_.

Answer (score 1):

*Men, women and children* is not a word, but a phrase (a noun phrase = NP <sup>1</sup> ), so you can not apply morphological terminology like *compounding* here.
I don't think there's a special name for NP formation via conjunction other than exactly that - NP formation by conjunction.

---

<sup>1</sup> Depending on theory, replace NP by DP (determiner phrase), assuming additional empty determiners for each noun.

Comment: What would be considered the head of the construction?

Comment: This is a potentially difficult issue depending on whether you restrict your syntax to binary branching. In the most simple way, you will have three NPs with N heads which are then brought together to a single subject NP by adjunction.

Comment: @player.mdl - are you asking if there is a term for "subject" when the subject in question is made up from more than one noun?

Comment: @Xxxxxx any noun phrase. The example simply happens to be contained in subject position.

Answer (score 1):

The example *Men, women and children are people* could have a compound noun *men, women, and children*, but it would be unwise to refer to it that way, using the term "compound noun", because of confusion with another quite different construction, also a "compound noun", which is morphological rather than syntactic and does not use a conjunction.  For instance, *woman child* is a compound noun, stressed on the first part of the compound, which refers to a person who is both a woman and a child.

So, although in the example, *men, women, and children* might be a compound noun, it shouldn't be called that, because it would be confusing.  I'll refer to it as a *conjoined noun* instead, to avoid that confusion.

I notice in other comments that *men, women, and children* is referred to as a conjunction of three noun phrases (or DPs, or subjects), rather than three nouns.  That's misleading, though it could be true.  The general rule in English is that several constituents of the same category can be conjoined, and since a NP (noun phrase) can be absent any overt determiner, in the example, we could be dealing with either a conjunction of three nouns or a conjunction of three NPs.  If we add a determiner or an adjective to the example, the situation becomes clear:

```
The men, women, and children are hungry.  
The men, the women, and the children are hungry.
```

The first has a conjunction of three nouns; the second has a conjunction of three NPs.  A standard example of structural ambiguity is

```
old men and women
```

which can have either the conjunction of nouns *men and women* modified by the adjective *old*, or else the conjunction of the two NPs *old men* and *women*.

In the original example, with neither determiner nor adjective to disambiguate, the two possible structures have the same sense, so far as I can tell.

Comment: "I notice in other comments that men, women, and children is referred to as a conjunction of three noun phrases (or DPs, or subjects), rather than three nouns. That's misleading, though it could be true." That's a good point, but isn't it then also misleading to call it a "conjoined noun", suggesting that it is a single noun? Rather, I understand your argument such that it's three nouns that are conjoned to one NP, so it should be "conjoined NP" or "noun conjunction", right?

Comment: @lemontree, no it's not misleading to suggest that the conjunction of 3 nouns is a single noun, because it is in fact a single noun.  This is another instance where traditional grammarians have been led astray by terminology.  Here, there are two good reasons for considering a conjunction of nouns to be a noun.  (1) It preserves the generalization that the conjunction of several constituents always has the same category as that of each constituent.  (2) A conjunction of several nouns behaves syntactically just like any other noun -- it can be modified by an adjective, e.g.

Comment: Okay, then we're again just presupposing completely different theories. To me, a noun is a word, and *men, women and children* certainly isn't a word.

Comment: @lemontree, the difference being that I have evidence for my theory (I gave you some), while you have no evidence at all for yours.

Comment: The "evidence" is that we defined a noun as a word. And under that definition, my claim that the phrase is not a word is just as correct as your claim with your completely different definition. In the framework I am assuming, there was nothing wrong about my statement. Whether the one or the other theory makes the more powerful, provable, ... predictions now is a different matter, but don't start with that "You have a different theory and therefore you are wrong" thing again. It's annoying. I misunderstood your argument, we are assuming different definitions and that's okay.

Comment: @lemontree.  No, no, no.  I couldn't disagree with you more.  We judge theories about a language by bringing forth facts about the language.  A terminological definition that you make might be relevant to a theory about you, but it's not relevant to the correctness of a theory about language.  Definitions can be convenient or inconvenient, traditional or novel, but they are not facts and are not theories.  You may be unwilling to call a multi-word constituent a noun, but that is just a fact about you, not a fact of language.

Comment: What is "a fact of language" to you? Things like *noun* are just words and not physical objects that stand for themselves, and they receive their meaning by those who define and use them, they do not have an objective or inherent meaning by themselves. So what a noun is does depend on a definition and not on objective physical facts. To clarify, I didn't say either that definitions are theories themselves, but parts of theories, and the theory that you base your explanations on involves different definitions (or concepts or whatever you may call it) than "my" (or traditional) theories do.

Comment: A fact of language is a naive speaker judgment that an expression is/is not acceptable in his language, or about its pronunciation, or about its interpretation, or the fact that the expression occurs in his speech when he speaks his language.  Others would give a different account, but most linguists would agree that a linguist's theoretical claim about a language is not a fact of that language just because he claims it.  If you want to persuade any linguist that a conjunction of nouns is not a noun, you must find evidence from English that this is so.  You can't just repeat your claim.